# Michigan City Boundary ESRI Shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, data, united-states

I want to run I-Tree "Canopy" and am looking for an official Esri shapefile that defines the city of Warren Michigan's jurisdictional boundaries.

Comment: Official from ESRI, or official from the City?

Answer (score 1):

Not an ESRI product, but here is a link to the [Michigan Geographic Data Library](https://www.mcgi.state.mi.us/mgdl/).

[Here is the data specific to Macomb County](https://www.mcgi.state.mi.us/mgdl/?rel=cext&action=Macomb).

Comment: here is another site where you could download osm data on a larger or smaller scale depending of the region (its worldwide) http://download.geofabrik.de/north-america.html or http://download.geofabrik.de/index.html